# MIPS load byte (lb) with offset

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to load a byte from a word saved in data:

```
.data
    number:
    .word w1
```

part of the .text:

```
stringlength:

    li $t2, 10
    li $t1, -1

    la $a0, number

loop:

    addiu $t1, $t1, 1

    lb $t0, $t1($a0)
    bne $t0, $t2, loop

    move $v0, $t1

jr $ra
```

*the code is not finished

My problem is with,

```
lb $t0, $t1($a0)
```

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic offset that will increment by 1, to check each byte in the string, to check wether it's equal to 10 (dec) or not.

QtSPIM raises an exception syntax error about this line,

What's the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such addressing mode, you'll just have to calculate the address yourself by adding the offset, such as:

```
add $t0, $t1, $a0
lb $t0, ($t0)
```

Comment: It does seem to work, but how exactly?
does it just load the address stored in $a0 + the value in $t1?

Comment: You want to access memory at address `$a0+$t1`. This code does that by calculating `$a0+$t1` first, then fetching the data from memory. `$t0` is used as temporary because it's gonna be overwritten anyway.